# Display text-only language hint on each tag for regular users

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

It's currently very difficult (not impossible) for regular users to determine if a tag on their site is currently set to one of the available language hints. For moderators, there is a drop-down box at the bottom of the tag wiki info page that lets us select a hint and save it. For users, nothing. The only way they can determine if a tag has a hint set is to enter in a `<!-- language: some-tag -->` hint on a post with code, wait for Prettify to do its thing, and then inspect the source code to see if the `<pre>` element containing the code has an actual language hint in it or if it just says default. I doubt many users even know that they can do that in order to figure it out.

Wouldn't it make sense to just remove the drop-down and save button that moderators see, and leave behind a text-only identifier of which language is currently set on each tag? Something like this:

[image: Show Language Hint]

This would let users easily see what is set without having to wonder or guess or submit requests to have it changed to something which is already set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great idea - the next build will include showing the code language to the general public on the tag info page.