# Adding a language hint to a tag for syntax highlighting

Tags: support, tags, syntax-highlighting

I am a moderator over at [Economics.SE](https://economics.stackexchange.com/), where some users have requested that syntax highlighting be implemented for questions that use the `r`, `Matlab`, or `python` programming languages. As I understand (from [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting/78312#78312) and [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work)), this requires that a *language hint* be added to the tags on our site corresponding to these languages.

Could someone explain how I can add the language hint to these tags?

Comment: I'm not a mod myself but I recall that you should have that option on one of the tags pages, maybe on info. Ah found it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237138/display-text-only-language-hint-on-each-tag-for-regular-users)

Comment: And there is one other issue. Your site seems to only honoring MathJax as extension and not prettify as can be learned from the enabled markdown extensions in [this site list](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=500&filter=!6Oe4rY*-cz.N2&run=true).

Answer (score 2):

I have recently embarked on a similar exercise at a site I moderate in:

[Any coding tags missing code language setting for syntax highlighting?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4391/any-coding-tags-missing-code-language-setting-that-makes-syntax-highlighting-aut)

and I am building on some earlier work by a fellow moderator there at:

[Syntax highlighting for pyqgis](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3221/syntax-highlighting-for-pyqgis).

I am currently clarifying the reputation needed to suggest language hints for syntax highlighting at:

[What reputation is needed to suggest language hints to be used for particular tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287063/what-reputation-is-needed-to-suggest-language-hints-to-be-used-for-particular-ta)