# What reputation is needed to suggest language hints to be used for particular tags?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, syntax-highlighting

In [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) it says:

> If you're curious whether a tag has a language hint, any user is
>   capable of checking by visiting that tag's wiki page. The language
>   hint (if any) that is currently being used for that tag will be
>   displayed at the very bottom, below the buttons for the wiki

At what reputation level can users suggest the language hint to be used for a tag via its tag wiki?

My understanding is that those with 20K+ or moderator privileges can approve such suggestions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently only moderators can change it. It is read-only text to everyone else, present solely so users can figure out which highlighter is being used for a given tag.

There is no mechanism in place whatsoever for "suggesting" it be changed outside of simply creating a new support request on Meta requesting it be changed for a given tag. There is no mechanism for high-reputation users. It's only a drop-down menu accessible to moderators.